# Adjust legend element alignment for chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Is there a way to use the standard legend and edit it somehow that it is not aligned centered and has e.g. fixed width for each element so it doesn't look so disordered?

I know the way to generate an html legend, but thus the functionality gets lost to turn datasets on or off, like it can be done with the built in legend.

What would be the best way to get the legend automatically ordered e.g. floating left with fixed dimensions for each element and keeping all interactions still available?
Thanx for your help.
[basic generated legend for chart.js (aligment centered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrFCH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having received not feedback on this issue, I guess this example may help others to get a quick solution, too, on how to create a sorted and much better looking legend for chart.js with keeping all interactions available.

This example generates fixed boxes for each item. It will break the legend items into a second row - keeping the colums width - while minimizing the width of the chart.

```js
function updateLegendAction(e, datasetIndex) {
 var index = datasetIndex;
    var ci = e.view.chart;
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
    // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
    meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
 document.getElementById("label"+index).style.opacity = document.getElementById("label"+index).style.opacity === '0.2' ? '1' : '0.2';
 // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
     ci.update();                                                                                      
};    

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Helvetica', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'grey';

var chart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 3,
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81]
  }, {
    label: "Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(15,187,25,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(15,187,25,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 3,
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [38, 55, 50, 65]
  },{
    label: "Third dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 3,
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [4, 56, 34, 21]
  },{
    label: "And so on...",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,20,20,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 3,
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [25, 13, 11, 5]
  }]
  },
  options: {
      responsive: false,
      //Define a new HTML Legend
      legendCallback: function(legendarray) {
            var legendHtml = [];
   legendHtml.push('<div class="boxxcontainer">');
            for (var i=0; i<legendarray.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                legendHtml.push('<div id="label' + i + '" class="containerItem" style="width:' + (100/(legendarray.data.datasets.length)-1) +'%;"> <div class="boxx" style="background-color:' + legendarray.data.datasets[i].fillColor + '; border-top:' + legendarray.data.datasets[i].borderWidth +'px solid ' + legendarray.data.datasets[i].borderColor +';"></div>');                    
                if (legendarray.data.datasets[i].label) {
                    legendHtml.push('<div class="boxxlabel" onclick="updateLegendAction(event, ' + '\'' + legendarray.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex + '\'' + ')">&nbsp;' + legendarray.data.datasets[i].label + '</div></div>');
                }                                                                              
            }         
   legendHtml.push('</div>');                                                   
            return legendHtml.join("");                                                        
        }, 
      legend: {
     display: false,
    },
     scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks:{
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
         }
      }]
     }
      },
}, newlegend);
var newlegend = document.getElementById("htmllegend").innerHTML = chart.generateLegend();
```

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
}

.boxxcontainer {
  margin-left:30px;
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}

.boxx {
  background-color: green;
  width: 10%;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 0%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.boxxlabel {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 86%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 125%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.containerItem {
  height: 30px;
  min-width:150px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="htmllegend"></div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```